# SQL, get just recent ( in one row) from many to many relation ship

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, many-to-many

I have 3 tables like

```
A. (Aid,person)

B. (Bid,event,InsertDate)

C. (Cid,Aid,Bid)
```

now I need to get last recent event base on `B.InsertDate` desc from joined `B.event` and `A.Person` (last event of each person) 
I tried join but that make multiple `A.Person` and `B.event`.
Can you guide me please?

Update:

for now I just add another lastUpdate column to person table and update that for each insert in Event table and made that equal to InsertDate. so my query is like:

```
SELECT
    A.person, B.event
    from tableA A
    join tableC C
    on A.Aid = C.Aid
    join tableB B
    on B.Bid = C.Bid and B.InsertDate = A.lastUpdate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  A.person,
  B.event,
  MAX(B.InsertDate)
FROM
  A
  JOIN C ON A.Aid = C.Aid
  JOIN B ON B.Bid = C.Bid
GROUP BY
  A.person,
  B.event
```

Answer (score 1):

May be something lyk this

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER (partition BY person ORDER BY B.InsertDate DESC) rn,
                A.person,
                B.event,
                B.InsertDate                    AS LastEventDate
         FROM   B
                JOIN (SELECT B.event,
                             Max(B.InsertDate) InsertDate
                      FROM   B
                      GROUP  BY B.event) sub
                  ON sub.event = B.event
                     AND sub.InsertDate = b.InsertDate
                JOIN A
                  ON A.Bid = C.Bid
                JOIN C
                  ON B.Bid = C.Bid)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: Still duplicate person! :D
Thanks anyway